# How does my LTE modem show up as an unknown type "modem"

Tags: networkmanager, modem

I have a Sierra Wireless RC7611 LTE module. I've put what I think are the relevant software versions below:

```
# uname -r
5.4.215
# nmcli --version
nmcli tool, version 1.22.10
# mmcli --version
mmcli 1.18.12
# qmicli --version
qmicli 1.30.8
```

Normally when the LTE module is powered on it appears as type gsm:

```
# nmcli dev
DEVICE    TYPE      STATE         CONNECTION
cdc-wdm0  gsm       disconnected  --
sit0      iptunnel  unmanaged     --
tunl0     iptunnel  unmanaged     --
lo        loopback  unmanaged     --
```

But I've seen one device where it appears as type modem:

```
# nmcli dev
DEVICE      TYPE      STATE         CONNECTION
cdc-wdm0    modem     disconnected  --
sit0        iptunnel  unmanaged     --
tunl0       iptunnel  unmanaged     --
lo          loopback  unmanaged     --
```

This isn't even a valid type according to the [documentation](https://developer-old.gnome.org/NetworkManager/stable/nmcli.html). How is it happening? I'm happy to dive into debugging further but I'm not even sure which part of the ecosystem this is coming from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out this was a [bug in NetworkManager](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/NetworkManager/NetworkManager/-/issues/1148), it's now [fixed](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/NetworkManager/NetworkManager/-/commit/0da9f059e106e669209460bc54faf675454d958a).